# Is it true that if $A=BA^{*}A$ then $A^{*}=B^{*}AA^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I wonder is it true that for any $n \times n$ matrices $A$, and $B$.//
If  $A=BA^{*}A$ is true, does it imply that $A^{*}=B^{*}AA^{*}$?//
I used mathematica to check the condition in 3 by 3 case, and it works, but could anyone have an idea to prove that this is true for n dimensions？//
Thanks!
P.S. I do have a proof for this when A and B are partial isometries, but it confuses me that whether it was true for any general matrices.

Comment: It's true if they are unitary :)

Comment: It is true if $A$ is invertible.  Slight modifications of Adolfo's answer show it need not be true for 2-by-2 matrices or for partial isometries.

Comment: @SissiSue: Sorry, what I said about Adolfo's answer showing it need not be true for partial isometries was wrong. I was forgetting one of the conditions.

Answer (score 5):

If $A^*$ denotes the adjoint matrix (complex conjugate) of $A$ that is not true. Take:

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{array} \right) \qquad B = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{array} \right) $$

Then:

$$A^* = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{array} \right) \qquad B^* = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{array} \right)$$

But:

$$BA^*A= \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{array} \right)
 \qquad B^*AA^* = \left( \begin{array}{c c}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{array} \right) $$

You need to impose more conditions if you want that result to be true or $*$ does not mean adjoint matrix.

EDIT: I changed $B$ and $B^*$ following Jonas Meyer's advice so now it is a complete counterexample.

Comment: But $BA^{*}A$ is not equal to $A$. I would like that to be true at first.

Comment: @SissiSue, Adolfo: Switch $B$ and $B^*$ and you will have a counterexample.

Comment: I see for general matrices I had to add condition that the determinant of the matrices is not equal to 0. Sepcial cases are A and B both partial isometries, then the thing works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have a brief proof for A and B both partial isometries? Mine is too long to believe it. Thank you so much.